# Getting a NPE on Java 11 jdeps tool when scanning Spring Boot .jar files

Tags: java, java-11, java-module

When I'm trying to find the Java modules that I need to link in my custom JRE, I do get an NPE from `jdeps` tool:

```
marc$ jdeps --module-path $JAVA_HOME/jmods --print-module-deps --multi-release 11 target/blha/jx1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/BOOT-INF/lib/*.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ModuleGraphBuilder.requiresTransitive(ModuleGraphBuilder.java:124)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ModuleGraphBuilder.buildGraph(ModuleGraphBuilder.java:110)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ModuleGraphBuilder.reduced(ModuleGraphBuilder.java:65)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ModuleExportsAnalyzer.modules(ModuleExportsAnalyzer.java:124)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.ModuleExportsAnalyzer.run(ModuleExportsAnalyzer.java:97)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask$ListModuleDeps.run(JdepsTask.java:1023)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:560)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.JdepsTask.run(JdepsTask.java:519)
    at jdk.jdeps/com.sun.tools.jdeps.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

Any idea how to find all modules that I need to link to the custom JRE for this Spring Boot project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely affected by [[JDK-8211887] jdeps throws NPE when analyzing javafx.media that references a non-existent class used to be in JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8211887), you have the same stack trace with the NPE at `ModuleGraphBuilder.java:124`.

This issue is resolved in Java 12 and suggested workaround for Java 11 is to use `--ignore-missing-deps` option. I'm not seeing a backport to Java 11 :(